# C# Implicit array declaration

Tags: c#, arrays, implicit

Basically, I want to be able to use `string.Split(char[])` without actually defining a char array as a separate variable. I know in other languages you could do like `string.split([' ', '\n']);` or something like that. How would I do this in C#?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a really nice way to do it:

```
string[] s = myString.Split("abcdef".ToCharArray());
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
string[] s = myString.Split('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but: `string.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n' });`

Comment: Note that in C# 3 you can make this slightly prettier by eliding the "char". The compiler will work out that new[]{x,y,z} means "new array of the best common type of x, y and z".

Comment: Awesome, good to know.  I'm guessing this is possible because of the type inference work done for LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this overload:

```
public String [] Split(params char [] separator)
```

like this:

```
yourstring.Split(' ', '\n')
```